# How to generate pass/fail report for android application using appium in android studio(using Testng)

Tags: android, testng, appium, appium-android

I want to generate the pass/fail reports for an **android application** using **android-studio** in **Appium** (with TestNG)

Any idea about the 3rd party tools that can link with the code and generate a **report** in **android studio**

I have tried **Extent report** but it does not provide reporting for application as i can't see any report file created there

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you configured it wrong. Extent reports old version and new version are bit different. Here is an example to generate Extent report. Create Extent report builder

```
@BeforeSuite
    @Parameters({"browser","URL","Env"})
    public void beforeSuite(String browser,String URL,String Env) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");
        String today = formatter.format(date);
        createDir = new CreateDirectories();
        createDir.createFolderWithSpecificName(OUTPUT_FOLDER + today);
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + today +"/"+ FILE_NAME);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Regression Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("BROWSER" , browser);
        extent.setSystemInfo("URL", URL);
        extent.setSystemInfo("ENVIRONMENT" , "ENV");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public synchronized void beforeClass() {
        ExtentTest parent = extent.createTest(getClass().getName());
        parentTest.set(parent);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public synchronized void beforeMethod(Method method) {
        ExtentTest child = parentTest.get().createNode(method.getName());
        test.set(child);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {

        StringBuilder inputArgs = new StringBuilder();
        Object objects[] = result.getParameters();

        for(Object obj : objects){
            if(obj==null){
                inputArgs.append("  ");
            }else{
                inputArgs.append(obj.toString());
            }
            inputArgs.append(" , ");
        }

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
            test.get().fail(result.getThrowable()+ "Input Parameters : "+inputArgs.toString());
        else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
            test.get().skip(result.getThrowable() + "Input Parameters : "+inputArgs.toString());
        else
            test.get().pass( " Test Passed. Input parameters : " +inputArgs.toString());
        extent.flush();
    }
```

Then Run ExtentReport With class `public class Base extends ExtentTestNGReportBuilder`

Another way is create listener. Configuration details available on extent report site.

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false" thread-count="5" verbose="1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utils.listners.ExtentTestNGIReporterListener"> 
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. your external report class should implement the `IReporter` class.
2. register your external report class as listener in your testNg xml runner.
3. verify your output file path again 
   It should work!!! Good luck :)!!!